# Global mixer volume automatically changed by QtAudioOutput

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, audio

When calling the start method of QAudioOutput in QT 5.1, it automatically sets my global system volume to 100%. How can I prevent that? I don't want to set an explicit volume, I just want it to remain unchanged. I have looked through the multimedia reference but I seem to be missing something, as I found no mention of this behavior.

Comment: I doubt this behaviour is intentional. Audio and video are a bit tricky to get platform independent. Under Linux gstreamer is used, under Windows it uses.... whatever. From the docs I'd say this is a Qt bug. Maybe you could report it here: https://bugreports.qt-project.org. And if it is not a bug, you will get very fast your response, what you did wrong. ;-)

Comment: I got exactly the same problem in Qt5.1, Archlinux. Have you found the solution?

Comment: Show the code you have tried.